# C# format a double with ToString, and dispay zero value

Tags: c#, formatting, double, tostring

I'm trying to find the best way to display a double in C# as follows:

- 7.345 should display as "73"
- 100.0 should display as "100"
- 0.234 shoud display as "02"

The input is a value between 0.00 and 10.00. I need to convert it to a filename. E.g. in case of a value of 5.4234, I should display "`img54.jpg`".

The problem is that I can't figure out how to display zero values in `ToString()` of doubles.

I tried this:

- `(10 * 7.345).ToString("##.")` => correct
- `(10 * 10.00).ToString("##.")` => correct
- `(10 * 0.000).ToString("##.")` => FAIL, doesn't display anything.
- `(10 * 0.000).ToString("D2")` => FAIL, D is not allowed in doubles

I can of course do some sophisticated string building, but if it's possible to use `ToString`, that would be much better of course.

Anyone an idea?

Comment: If your input is constrained to be between 0.00 and 10.00, why are you worrying about 100.0?

Comment: Because 10 * 10.0 = 100.0.I want to map a value between 0.0 and 10.0 to a value to a int value between 00 and 99 AND 100 :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you want 0.00 to display as? `"00"`?

In that case you can try with format `ToString("00.")` instead.

Comment: This is definitely the way to go. Rather then using "##." as your mask, just use "00" and that should give you exactly what you are looking for. At least for your test cases listed.

Answer (score 1):

Can you simply check if the double is 0? and If it is, set img00.jpg to your filename. That seems a lot easier than reworking your algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you convert it to an int?

```
int result = (int)(input * 10.00);
return result.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just convert to int before formatting like this:
((int)(10 * 7.345)).ToString("D2")

Answer (score 0):

If you always have the input number of this format: #.###

You can multiply it by 1000 and divided by 100 and cast the result to an integer.

7.345 * 1000 = 7345 / 100 = 73.45 => Convert.ToInt32 => 73

0.000 * 1000 = 0 / 100 = 0 => Convert.ToInt32 = 0

---

Or you can multiply by 10 and convert to Integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
return ((int)(input * 10.00)).ToString().SubString(0, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double val = 7.345;
string result = val.ToString("0.#").Replace(".","");
```